# Как получить email пользователя, запускающего скрипт

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть расшаренная на редактирование таблица google, нужно получать email пользователя, который запускает скрипт, для дальнейшей организации "разграничения доступа", под которым понимается скрытие/открытие строк/столбцов, создание кастомных меню для определенных пользователей. Из-за антиспамных и секьюрных политик google не позволяет просто получить email пользователей, открывающих google docs. Но на буржуйских просторах stackoverflow нашел вот этот [топик](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322476/get-the-user-who-clicked-on-the-button-in-the-spreadsheet), там парень предлагает красивое решение проблемы. Но решение неоднозначное, я так до конца и не понял как оно корректно работает. Но суть в том что оно работает!, правда опять с одним "НО", работает оно только на платном домене google.
Есть пользователь из платного домена user@progger.pro, у него есть таблица google которая расшарена с правами редактирования обычным пользователям user1@gmail.com и user2@gmail.com. В таблице код, который при открытии показывает email открывшего документ пользователя:

```html
function onOpen()
{
var user = getUserEmail();
Browser.msgBox(user);
}

function getUserEmail() {
  var userEmail = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("userEmail");
  if(!userEmail) {
    var protection = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("A1").protect();
    // tric: the owner and user can not be removed
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    var editors = protection.getEditors();
    if(editors.length === 2) {
      var owner = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getOwner();
      editors.splice(editors.indexOf(owner),1); // remove owner, take the user
    }
    userEmail = editors[0];
    protection.remove();
    // saving for better performance next run
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("userEmail",userEmail);
  }
  return userEmail;
}
```

Все работает идеально, но опять же про неоднозначность решения, при дебаге функции `getUserEmail()` выполняется `var userEmail = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("userEmail")` и возвращается userMail.
При попытке реализовать все вышеописанное в google таблице, созданной обычным user1@gmail.com, ничего не работает, вне зависимости от того кто открывает таблицу возвращается email владельца. Почему функция `getUserEmail()` созданная user1@gmail.com не хочет работать? Есть ли другой метод решить проблему определения пользователя открывающего общую таблицу google.

Answer (score 2):

Мое личное мнение заключается в том, что подход к реализации подобных решений неверен в корне. Сначала говорят про безопаснсть, про необходимость идентификации и недопустимость утечки информации. Затем, практически сразу, о том, что подобные меры чему-то там мешают.

#### Ремарка про "дебаг"

Невозможно сэмулировать Simple trigger из штатного отладчика. Я таких средств не видел.

#### 2017-09-04 Дебаг. Серверное логирование

Stackdriver log https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/stackdriver-logging-for-google-apps.html

## Проблема №1

Кто выполняет скрипт? Например, файл доступен для всех на редактирование. Какой пользователь будет вызывать `PropertiesService`? Аноним? Тогда он будет хранить все настройки для всех анонимов в одной области видимости. Или это должен быть какой-то идентифицированный аноним? Тут уже нарушение самой анонимности. Даже рассуждая лгически, можно придти к выводу, что пользователь, который не прошел процедуру авторизации, не может вызвать `PropertiesService`, за него это делает владелец.

## Проблема №2

Обработка ошибок на уровне прав. Если обработать ошибки первой функции, то можно увидеть неожиданные вещи

```
function onOpen() {
  try {
    var user = getUserEmail();
  } catch (err) {
    var user = JSON.stringify({
      err: err.message,
      stack: err.stack
    });
  }
  Browser.msgBox(user);
}
```

Оказывается, проблема может быть не только в том, что "неверно" определяется пользователь, но и в том, что сам метод не совсем правильно реализован. Также посмотрите, сколько защищенных диапазонов A1 насоздавал этот код.

## Проблема №3

Кто разрешил запускать скрипт? Сначала кажется, что это проблема №1, но это не так. Разрешает выполнять скрипт сам пользователь. В общем плане одна и та же программа, но с разными параметрами авторизации будут выполняться по-разному. Стоит обратить внимание, что Simple triggers https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions идентичны по вызову Installable triggers.

Существует ли решение для этих проблем? Как мне кажется, пока нет. В Гугл до сих пор играются с областями видимости и с доступными свойствами, открывая границы доступного и превозмогая области дозволенного. Полагаться на предлагаемую реализацию не стоит.

Разработчику стоит обратить взгляд на штатные проверенные средства. Например, реализовав отдельное приложение с верно настроенной авторизацией, можно точно контроллировать пользователя. Таблицы не являются панацеей, и какие-либо избыточные фантазии на их тему никак реализовать нельзя. Никаких хитрых "но" и "как-нибудь" тут быть не может. Стоит понимать, почему это работает именно так и не иначе. Может ли Гугл это изменить? Безусловно. Но когда?

Небольшое наблюденние [Эффективный пользователь против Активного](https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/c367cd3a24a2c2a92b83eef3ef2e07ea) на эту тему.